# Why isn't my actor stopped on exception in akka.net with F#

Tags: f#, akka.net

I'm playing around with akka.net and trying to understand Supervision. I thought I got it but it doesn't work as I expect it to.

I try to get a small sample with a monitor and a child actor where the monitor should restart the child on an exception in the child. It seems like the child is restarting, but I don't understand why since the code doesn't seem to execute my `SupervisorStrategy`. I change my strategy to return `Directive.Stop` to check if I can stop the actor, but that doesn't work either. So right now it seems like I have an unstoppable actor which is a good thing as long as I don't want to kill it :). The code to run the sample is below:

```
open Akka
open Akka.Actor
open Akka.Tools
open Akka.FSharp
open System

type MonitorMessage =
    | Create

type ChildMessage =
    | Ping
    | Kill

let test() =
    let systemName = "my-system"
    let system = System.create systemName (Configuration.load())

    let handleChildMessage = function
        | Ping ->
            printfn "Received %A" Ping
            printfn "Pong: %A" (DateTime.Now.Ticks)
        | Kill ->
            1/0 |> ignore

    let createChild parent id =
        spawnOpt parent (id.ToString()) (actorOf handleChildMessage)
            [ SpawnOption.SupervisorStrategy (Strategy.OneForOne (fun error ->
                match error with
                | _ ->
                    printfn "%A" error
                    Directive.Stop
                    )) ]

    let handleMonitorMessage (actor:Actor<MonitorMessage>) message =
        match message with
        | Create ->
            let sender = actor.Sender()
            sender <! createChild actor (Guid.NewGuid())

    let monitor = spawn system "monitor" (actorOf2 handleMonitorMessage)
    let child = monitor <? Create |> Async.RunSynchronously
    child <! Ping
    child <! Kill
    child <! Ping

test()
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking how much/little of F# do you know? The code has very basic mistakes in it.

Comment: `1/0 |> ignore` throws, `()` doesn't. It would probably be better to use `failwith` or `raise` there, though.

Comment: @GuyCoder, I do know a fair amount of F#. I just set up a small sample in a couple of minutes. Out of curiosity, what mistakes do you think of.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev, `1/0` was just me forcing and error. Of course the other two options such are better :)

Comment: I only looked at the code quickly and saw the `1/0 |> ignore`. Any time I see `|> ignore` I focus in on it. If it is related to C# which has a side effect then it is more likely to be correct but if it is with pure F# then I really take a close look. Seeing the `|> ignore` then identified the `1/0` which was another red flag. The obvious replacement `1\0 |> ignore` in this code would be `()`. The unit type `()` is a basic part of F# and not using it was a big red flag.

Comment: Because the code would have required me to install more code to compile it and test it I stopped looking as I don't need the bloat on my computer. I did see the other answer for akka.net that you gave which was accepted, so one side of reasoning said you know what you are doing, but this was saying you lacked a basic concept. Thus I was confused and asked the question.

Comment: @GuyCoder, I sort of know what I'm doing... I hope ;). Should have figured this one out myself too, and think twice about what code I add to questions since these kind of minor things might draw attention from the actual question.

Comment: I had my share of things I wanted to redo. I look upon it myself  as you can't learn if you don't make mistakes. Hope to see more questions and answers from your here related to F#. :) You should edit the question with a better version for that function as it will not change the meaning of the question and distract others in the future.

Comment: After noting the unit type I checked the F# tags and noticed that there were quite a few questions that should have the `unit-type` tag so I added them. I actually learned some interesting things by reading [them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23+unit-type?sort=votes&pageSize=50)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your `createChild` function won't create an actor as a child of monitor. It's caused by the fact that you've passed actor system to spawnOpt function - this means, that spawned actor will be a top level one (living directly under actor system kernel). You need to change that to `spawnOpt parent` in order to create it as a parent's child.
2. Supervision strategy option means, that actor having it, will apply it to its children. Therefore you need to set it up for the monitor, not the children.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it when back at a computer. Sending the system to the child was just me copied the wrong version of the code, and I've updated the code. Of course the strategy is for the monitor, since all the children should follow the same rule. I should have realized that myself but probably was a little bit tired.